# Trying to populate dropwdown list with a kml file data and save coordinates to be use later for distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kml

my idea is that a user will have 2 dropdown lists of places contained in the KML file for location 1 and location 2 and after selecting the locations it will show the relative distance between location. my problem is how can I get the name of these locations in a dropdown and at the same time save the values of the coordinates so I can make the calculations is javascript or jquery

The KML file looks like this

```
<Placemark>
<name>Bobber&#39;s Restaurant at Alhonna Resort</name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
<styleUrl>#style92</styleUrl>
<Point>
  <coordinates>-92.752266,38.199223,0.000000</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>Bulldog&#39;s Beach House</name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
<styleUrl>#style13</styleUrl>
<Point>
  <coordinates>-92.790977,38.101349,0.000000</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: if html page is static then can dynamically parse the KML using JavaScript APIs (generic XML Parser or something like geoxml3).

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_directions_linktoB.html)?

Comment: cool I'll take a look at geoxml3 hopefully I can figure it out thanks guys!.. @geocodedzip while the sample is not necessarily what I'm looking for, it will probably will give me an idea thank! The only info I need is the relative distance from one point to the other I said relative because it's how much gas will it cost me to go from one one marina to another in a lake.